# Mongoose conditional field value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a project with NodeJS and MongoDB and I am using Mongoose. In my database I am storing the companies with the opening and closing hours. I also have a field `isOpen` which is a boolean and I want to know if it's possible to dynamically change the value of `isOpen` in mongoDB according to current date and the the opening hours of the company.

```js
{
    openingHours {
        opens: Number,
        closes: Number
    },
    isOpen: Boolean // should depend on the current date and openinghours
}
```

PS: I saw that it was possible to put a function over the field `required`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use virtual property to get that functionality.

```
var storeSchema = new Schema({
  openingHours {
        opens: Number,
        closes: Number
  },
});

storeSchema.virtual('isOpen').get(function () {
  const currentTime = Date.now();
  const currentHour = currentTime.getHours();
  return this.openingHours.opens >= currentHour && currentHour < this.openingHours.closes;
});
```

More information about virtual property you can find in [official documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals).

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to be the best solution !